# Android @+id in layout xml crashing app

Tags: xml, android, layout, crash

Firstly, I am new to android development. My app has been working fine with a number of different activities up until today.

I have been trying to add a new `<Button />` element to one of my layout xml files. However, if I give it a new id (e.g., `android:id="@+id/button_unique"`) my app crashes on load, presumably as the resources are being loaded. If I change the id to an existing id (or remove `android:id` attribute completely) then the app loads fine.

The new resource id does appear in R.java. However, I can see a `No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f060000` error in the logcat console. I'm not sure if this is related?

Perhaps i'm making a silly mistake somewhere, but if anybody could help me get to the bottom of this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm now having this issue and am sad about it. :(

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by rebuilding from scratch as the other post said. I entered `ant clean` before I built.

Answer (score 1):

It is really tough to know without you posting a code example, but one possible solution that could work is after naming the new unique button, is resave and rebuild the project before running it again in the emulator. That will resave the new change in R.java which does not happen without the force of resave/rebuild. Hope that helps. Good Luck!